# odoo Missing dependencies qweb (After DB restore)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

[image: ERROR]

So after restoring a database dump the frontend resources appear to be corrupted on my Odoo installation.

I do not see what I would consider to be critical errors in the server logs and all the resources appear to load correctly (No 404 errors).

I have heard people having similar issues after an database restore if they do not backup the filestore as well. So I am leaning towards this being a filestore <--> DB issue (ie. the db is referencing items in the filestore that have been moved, although I have seen no error indicating this).

Does anyone have any advice on how to best debug this issue?

Also... full disclosure, I have posted this on Odoo's forum as well (go ahead and hate me for that if you will). Here is the posting 
[odoo Missing dependencies qweb](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo-missing-dependencies-qweb-122535)

Comment: Have you tried opening the client in asset debug mode (adding `?debug=assets` to the URL)? If it loads then, then you need to remove the asset entries from `ir_attachment` table, so that Odoo would regenerate them, eg. `delete from ir_attachment where name ilike '%asset%';`

Comment: I have used ?debug=assets however the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Sudhanshu, I am going to post the answer for this. And thanks again for all your help last night. That was epic!

This answer will likely not help anyone. The solution to the problem was rather unique and unexpected. The Main Layout template for the front end was overridden. The new layout was missing critical components which included the csrf_token. Without this Qweb could not properly load and as a result  many other modules failed which had Qweb as a dependency or referenced the csrf_token.

I have no explanation for the overridden template, except "It wasn't me".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you can delete the references from the db, Odoo will re-create them and that will remove the error.

Comment: Since you already have the backup, maybe we can give it a try.

Try running the following query over your database

update ir_attachment set store_fname='' where mime_type='application/javascript';

Comment: I ran the above query and restarted the server, odoo automatically created new files on the file system and the server was running smoothly without any issues.

So maybe that can help

Comment: update ir_attachment set store_fname='' where mime_type='application/javascript'

Comment: Sudhanshu, I will try this approach tonight. I will mark this correct or vote up if it turns out to be the solution. I think it just might work.

Comment: If it doesn't we can try a different approach. 
Also you can send me the server logs and we can see if we can get something from that.

Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, send me your email please.

Comment: Its sudhanshugupta7@gmail.com

Comment: Sudhanshu just so you are aware. I have tested this. You may want to do the same (just for reference). I updated store_fname = '' and the store_fname was restored the first time. I did it a second time and it would not restore the data. Only when I deleted the record did it restore it. I found this unusual. Just thought you should know. Try your update query a second or third time. See if it consistently restores the store_fname. If it fails to restore, try deleting the records.

Comment: Also I sent you an email.

Comment: No, I am working on it right now. It appears it is not related. Are you available to discuss this? I would appreciate some help. Can you skype me phillipstack

Comment: I had a similar issue after database import on odoo 10. I initially tried running @sudhanshuGupta 's "update" statement. Initially it resulted in empty .js pages. 
Inspired by the concept however, I ran:
`delete from ir_attachment where mimetype = 'application/javascript';`
then restarted odoo. All js dependency issues were fixed.